# How do I include additional folders on JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

How can I add a specific folder to jhipster? The default folders inside content are included. I've added a folder named "sample-files" and that folder is not included on the content bundle neither on the .war publish file.

Comment: We need more information to give a correct answer.  What client framework do you use?  AngularJS (which uses Gulp) or Angular (which uses Webpack)?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks for the help! I've fixed implementing this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For webpack, use `CopyWebpackPlugin` in `webpack/webpack.common.js`, you'll find examples there.